# how to download google fonts in version bold

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

Im using SourceSansPro-Bold. I have one file ttf downloaded,  and I have other format declared as google links. But my question is if the these links are correct?

The problem is that Google links has word 'V4 declared, probably version 4, but I need fonts in version "bold".

How to check if there are the same fonts (both in bold version)?

Or how to modify google link to get bold font for sure?

Css Font definition:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'source sans pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: font-url('SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf');
  src: font-url('SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
       local('Source Sans Pro Bold'), local('SourceSansPro-Bold'),
       url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/sourcesanspro/v4/toadOcfmlt9b38dHJxOBGBlTL9oEQvYTI0YAW1-Ysv0.eot) format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/sourcesanspro/v4/toadOcfmlt9b38dHJxOBGNbE_oMaV8t2eFeISPpzbdE.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Google font declaration with V4 string inside:

```
http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/sourcesanspro/v4/toadOcfmlt9b38dHJxOBGBlTL9oEQvYTI0YAW1-Ysv0.eo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select which weight of font you want here:
https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Source+Sans+Pro.

**If you want to download these files locally.**

1. Visit the `href` from the `<link>`
2. Visit the `url:` from the `@font-face` of the font you need.
3. This will download the font.

Comment: Looks very good:), I have only one question: does such import link will downalod fonts in a few formats like: ttf, woff, eof or others?  I need them to be fully supported  in all browsers, right?

Comment: Just woff. Woff is supported in most modern browsers and devices. Do you need support for old browsers?

Comment: would be nice to support some older too... Can I do something like          @font-face {
  font-family: 'source sans pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: font-url('SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf');
  src: font-url('SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
       local('Source Sans Pro Bold'), local('SourceSansPro-Bold'),
       url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700);      
}

Comment: is it correct to put this google link from your tool to font-family definition?

Comment: Google only ship woff. If you want to use the othe types, you'll need to convert them or use a different provider.

Comment: Generally you solution works on my local instance... but it's not working on Amazon EC2 instance:) strange ...

Comment: Google ships all kind of formats, not only WOFF. Google delivers different CSS rules depending on the user agent and will reference the font format which is supported by the requesting browser. To download all font variants and create a X-Browser CSS definition you can use a tool like http://www.localfont.com/